# Docker swarm service with replicas vs single container with process forking capability

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I'm starting out with docker swarm. So far i had a single container which had an internal load balancer (gunicorn, uvicorn and starlette). I was able to setup concurrency settings of this stack for the bigger throughput. Now i see i can completely remove the load balancing aspect of the container and simply use Docker swarm service with a preset number of replicas. What is the recommended practice? I read somewhere that if you fork or create subprocesses you loose some monitoring functionality of the swarm tools.

Comment: One big advantage to docker swarm is that it can span multiple hosts, which simply isn't possible with a process-forking model.

Comment: A good answer requires details that are not in your question. Using the Swarm Routing Mesh is simple. If you want to provide SSL certificates (HTTPS) I prefer to use an external load balancer or NGINX. If you have a hybrid Swarm Linux/Windows), then it gets complicated. I don't think there is one solution that fits all.